# ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘BiocGenerics’

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, quick-install-package

I am trying to install this package "BiocGenerics" in R and getting this error.

> BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org Using Bioconductor 3.6
>   (BiocInstaller 1.28.0), R 3.4.2 (2017-09-28). Installing package(s)
>   ‘BiocGenerics’ trying URL
>   'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/src/contrib/BiocGenerics_0.24.0.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 43393 bytes (42 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 42 KB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘BiocGenerics’ ...
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading Creating a new generic function for ‘append’ in package ‘BiocGenerics’ Creating a new generic function
>     for ‘as.data.frame’ in package ‘BiocGenerics’ Creating a new generic
>     function for ‘cbind’ in package ‘BiocGenerics’ Error :
>     identical(as.call(parse(text = old_code)[[1L]]), body[[7L]][[3L]]) is
>     not TRUE Error in apply_hotfix73465(getGeneric("cbind")) :    hotfix
>     failed for generic function cbind() Error : unable to load R code in
>     package ‘BiocGenerics’ ERROR: lazy loading failed for package
>     ‘BiocGenerics’
> - removing ‘/home/hamna/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BiocGenerics’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/RtmprEuKCy/downloaded_packages’ installation path not
>   writeable, unable to update packages: BiocGenerics, littler, cluster, 
>   foreign, MASS, Matrix, mgcv, nlme, rpart, survival Warning message: In
>   install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :   installation of
>   package ‘BiocGenerics’ had non-zero exit status

I have tried installing it manually but it is failing. And then I tried this command on terminal

> sudo apt-get install r-bioc-biocgenerics

This helped me but it installed older version which is not valid for my final package "hgu133plus2.db"

Please help!
Best,

Answer (score 0):

[This was answered](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/104372/) on the Bioconductor support site.

There is an issue with R version 3.4.2 which required a patch. The best solution is to upgrade to at least 3.4.3.

Comment: I must tell you that I am using ubuntu and I just found that there is no release 3.4.3 for ubuntu. can you please comment.
Thanks

Comment: There certainly is a 3.4.3 for Ubuntu. You may need to add CRAN to your package source list, or download a deb for your version. Start here: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/.